# Darkening Image

Tags: java, image, image-processing

I am trying to darken an image in java but instead it is turning plain black.

Here is the code that i am using..

```
    float[] elements = {factor};

    Kernel kernel = new Kernel(1, 1, elements);
    ConvolveOp op = new ConvolveOp(kernel);

    BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), image.getType());
    op.filter(image, bufferedImage);
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: what is the factor you're using??

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Thanks the factor was wrong was doing it with a minus by mistake xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing the right number for the factor, a really good way to experiment with this is with the Gimp, you can go to filters -> generic -> convolution matrix and try out different factors, I can darken my image with a factor 0.7 and very low becomes too black.

Let me know how it went.